# Where to Set EXPO_DEBUG value in ReactNative app?

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo

When I try to login in expo I got this error :

```
[exp] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Do you know where exactly I have to set the value of `EXPO_DEBUG`?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but it seems like there is a problem with expo's auth system: https://twitter.com/expo_io/status/923466891837845504

Comment: yeah you're right, but i'm still wondering where to set that parameter :D

Comment: Where do I find the actual log file?

Comment: CD in your project file open command and try

Answer (score 19):

`EXPO_DEBUG` is an environment variable, so you can set it by typing `export EXPO_DEBUG=true` in your shell.

Comment: @hendra1 are you on windows? I think in that case you can use `set EXPO_DEBUG=true`

Comment: yes I'm on windows.. Ok set function is available thanks

Answer (score 11):

Just simply put the following commands in Windows os in sequence it will definitely work.

1:

```
cd Project_Dir>Set EXPO_DEBUG=true
```

2:

```
cd Project_Dir>expo start
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @rahulpatel it's working fine. Thank again for your contribution.

Answer (score 6):

find the following solution according to os

Linux OS then type in shell export EXPO_DEBUG=true

Windows OS then type in console set EXPO_DEBUG=true

Mac os then type in console set EXPO_DEBUG=true

Comment: Thank you for adding Mac os Instruction. It would be good thank you

Answer (score 4):

When you add some library into your project. then this type of problem occurs. This problem also occur for me when i try to add some navigator library into my react native project it happens then...

so if you are in a Linux OS then type in shell 
   ***export EXPO_DEBUG=true***

or if you are in a Windows OS then type in console
   ***set EXPO_DEBUG=true***

After adding the line in console/Shell i hope project will work again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simple:

```
$env:EXPO_DEBUG = 'true'
```

in power shell

Answer (score 3):

This issue arises with the latest version on node which in my case is 12.13.1.

There are suppose to be some changes made in the node_module.

Go to node_module/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js and change your var sharedBlacklist to

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/ 
];
```

Answer (score 2):

MY problem was solve by running

> npm install

inside current Project directory 
if it still not work
than update expo to new latest version 
and restart project again

Answer (score 2):

This works.

exp start
Cancel ctrl c
then do exp build:android.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted node_module and then re run npm install, and it worked

Answer (score 1):

in windows use cmd type `set EXPO_DEBUG = 'true'`
then close cmd open again in the project file type `expo start`
if it works graduation  :) 
if not: in project path open node_modules folder and open this path `node_module/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js` 
edit the file 
replace var haredBlacklist ... 
to this code

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/ 
];
```

Answer (score 0):

just open your command prompt 
run Set EXPO_DEBUG=ture (not a project directorty)
go to project directory  run expo start(in a project directory)

Answer (score 0):

in mac OS export EXPO_DEBUG=true

or if you are in a Windows OS set EXPO_DEBUG=true